# Sum values from loop in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

i need count total number of aws instances in all region and I write this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[*].[RegionName]" --output text); do
      aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --region $region --output text | wc -l
done
```

The output is like this:

```
...
0
0
0
48
0
0
0
...
```

Is there a way to get the total of these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
#!/bin/bash
SUM=0
for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[*].[RegionName]" --output text); do
      I="$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --region $region --output text | wc -l)"
      let SUM=SUM+I
done

echo "$SUM"
```